# Connect to a heroku database with pgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I would like to manage my Heroku database with `pgadmin` client. By now, I've been doing this with `psql`.
When I use data from `heroku pg:credentials` to connect de DB using `pgadmin`, I obtain:

> An error has occurred:
>
> Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  permission denied for database
> "postgres" DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

How to achieve the connection?

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Open the "Properties" of the Heroku server in pgAdminIII and change the "Maintenance DB" value to be the name of the database you want to connect to.

[image: pgAdmin III - New Server Registration]

The default setup is suitable for DBAs et al who can connect to any database on the server, but apparently that isn't true in your case.

Comment: As [suggested in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11769894/26510), you'll need to enable SSL by choosing "SSL | SSL | require" in the connection dialog as well, or else it will still fail to connect.

Comment: if you have Rails App you can access DB using https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db

Comment: I am getting error on pgadmin 3 that the server you are trying to connect is not between 8.4 and 9.3 and it connects but shows a list of 159 databases with error popups all the time.

Comment: This just stopped working for me? Does it still work for anyone?

Comment: @Ced yeah me too now - Windows had decided to turn on my firewall and block  that port :-/

Comment: @RuneJeppesen, Heroku says they can update the server connection properties (database name/username/password) any time.

Answer (score 122):

After you change the Maintenance DB name as suggested by [araqnid's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11775090/238722), you should also add your database to the DB restrictions field because without this you will see thousands of databases and you may not be able to find yours in the list if the list is too long.

More details here - [How to hide databases that I am not allowed to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663639/how-to-hide-databases-that-i-am-not-allowed-to-access/13298802#13298802)

Comment: +1 and when adding the db name, be sure to quote it in single quotes since it will be used to dynamically generate an `IN` clause to filter the db list.

Comment: Thank you! And as its update mentions, in pgAdmin 4, do not add quotes.

Answer (score 103):

### This is for pgAdmin 4

In order to connect pgAdmin to your database (postgres instance in Heroku), do the following:

1. Login to Heroku, and select the application in which you have the database
   [image]
2. Select the **Resources** tab and then click on "Heroku Postgres Ad-on" (see below). This will open up a new tab.
   [image]
3. Select the **Settings** tab and then click on "View Credentials..." (see below)
   [image]

   You will get the following information that you will use in pgAdmin:

   [image]
4. Go to pgAdmin, and create a new server
   [image]
5. In the **General** tab, give a useful name
   [image]
6. In the **Connection** tab, fill the info you got at Heroku
   [image]
7. In order to avoid seeing thousands of databases, you need to add your database name to DB restriction in the **Advanced** tab (see below)
   [image]

Comment: i'm getting Unable to connect to server:

FATAL: permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Comment: thank you so very much, i was totally missing the last bit with the advanced tab!

Comment: @nassim Make sure you change the "Maintenance Database" field in the "Connection" tab to the database after the "/" in the URI from Heroku.

Answer (score 22):

We require SSL for connections outside Heroku. Please verify whether you're forcing SSL in your client.

Answered more thoroughly here: [Connecting pgAdmin3 to Postgres on Heroku](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21869/connecting-pgadmin3-to-postgres-on-heroku)

We don't allow connections to the `postgres` database, so be sure to set Maintenance DB to your database name, and be sure to use SSL.

Comment: Do I need any kind of files/keys to force SSL? (excuse me for the ignorance)

Comment: typically graphical interfaces have a SSL checkbox somewhere. I don't use pgadmin, but based on the docs[1] it looks like there's an SSL tab in the connection config dialog. [1] http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html

Comment: When I clicked SSL tab, it asked me for certificates and a key, and I didn't know the values for them.
Although, buy setting the maintenance DB name to my heroku DB name, I could connect configurating only the 'Properties' tab, without having to specify nothing about SSL (this being done apparently automatically)

Comment: In order to change the properties, disconnect to the server first

Answer (score 11):

Change the Maintenance Database to the name of your Database, e.g. dva70000p0090. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

the db password local isnt the same db password heroku. please check the heroku ip postgtres address and extrac

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).