# How to hide databases that I am not allowed to access

Tags: heroku, pgadmin

When I connect to my `Heroku` - `Postgresql` database via `pgAdmin3`, It lists all the tables (about 2600). Every time I open the pgAdmin3 I have to find my own database.

Is there a way to hide databases that I'm `not allowed` to access ?

Answer (score 458, accepted):

Had the same issue, as its a shared space on AWS with 1000 other DBs.

**pgAdmin 3**

1. Make sure you are disconnected from your server.
2. Right click your Server -> properties -> Advanced tab.
3. In 'DB restriction' type in the name of your database(s) **enclosed in *single* quotes and separated by spaces**. E.g.  `'dback447'`

**pgAdmin 4**

Same as above, but on step 3 do not use quotes, just the plain DB name. E.g `dback447`

**pgAdmin 4 version 6.1**

Same as above, but press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after entering the name of each database. Commas or spaces take your string as a name of one single database.

And you have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> even if you want to type only one database name, otherwise the <kbd>Save</kbd> button ignores your changes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just want to add that you have to be disconnected from the server first before doing this, otherwise the DB restriction field will be grayed out

Comment: Another thing: use single quotes!

Comment: @Chin: I updated the answer based on your comment. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @luigi7up: I updated the answer based on your comment. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: how it is done in pgadmin4? There is no advanced tab in pgadmin4.

Comment: @Roman AFAIK how this is done in pgadmin4 is by trashing that and using pgadmin3.

Comment: Please all requests for this on pgadmin4 redirects to this page. pgAdmin4 has a different config. Is there anyone in the house that can be of help? thanks in advance

Comment: In PgAdmin 4, single quotes doesn't work anymore. Just the plain database name.

Comment: For pgAdmin 4-4.2 you need to separate them using either a comma or tab according to the instructions. I tried this with seven databases but only one of them shows up when I connect the server. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I'm trying to find this answer! Why do I keep getting "DB NOT FOUND" error. Turned out I just need to quote the thing. And sadly I tried to find the solution for hours. Thanks!!

Comment: In the V6 of pgAdmin I was unable to get this to work using the single quotes. Without the quotes worked as described.

Answer (score 17):

pgAdmin 4 does not contain the 'DB Restriction' which is the only reason I am not using it, forcing me to settle for pgAdmin 3.

There was a ticket opened up to add this functionality in pgAdmin 4 ... https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1918

Comment: pgadmin 4 sucks. Its slow and has lots of bugs

Comment: I'm using pgAdmin 4 now and DB restriction works great.

Answer (score 16):

The latest version of pgAdmin 4 (2.0) has the DB restriction property too in the "Advanced" tab of the server connection property, much the same as in pgAdmin 3. No quotes needed.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with only 10 other DBs and Matt Stevens' answer was only partly helpful ie at first it helped and then I got access to another DB on the same server.

I did all as described and it shoed no DB at all. In 'DB restriction' you type in the name of your databases enclosed in **single quotes and separated by commas**. E.g. 'db1'**,** 'db2'.

Answer (score 6):

Don't enclose in single quotes in pgAdmin 4.5, it will not work if you do.

Comment: same for pgAdmin 4.6