# PGAdmin - Why is DB Restriction (and Advanced Properties) Disabled?

Tags: database, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm hoping to restrict the number of databases I see in the browser tree/heirachy since it's an AWS server with hundreds of DBs. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663639/how-to-hide-databases-that-i-am-not-allowed-to-access/29390460) I found how to do that. But I can't edit this field (DB Restriction). Click, double click, right click, etc no luck.

I found that it says

> Note: you must ensure that the pg_hba.conf file of the server from
>   which you are connecting allows connections from the host of the
>   client.

In the documentation. Is this the glaring, obvious answer? If so is there a way for me interact with the pg_hba.conf of a remote server that I am not an admin on? Or is there some other reason why I can't edit this field?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please disconnect to the server first.
Now once the server is disconnected then right click on that server open the `Server -> Properties` dialog and you should be able to see it editable.