# PGAdmin shows excessive amount of database from Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I'm learning some backend stuff, I made a test database locally and filled some data, and then I dump the database to an SQL file with the following command:

```
pg_dump -U USERNAME DATABASE —no-owner —no-acl -f backup.sql
```

And finally restore it to Heroku:

```
heroku pg:psql —app APPNAME < backup.sql
```

There is only 1 database I’m deploying, however, when I use PGAdmin to connect to it, it shows more than 2000 databases and crashes my computer:

[image: screenshot of pgAdmin]

Where are all these databases coming from?

Comment: Tables and databases are different things. I don't use Heroku, but I suspect every time you are doing a restore you are creating a new database. Look at the Postgres logs for confirmation.

Comment: Thank you for your correction @AdrianKlaver, I’ve updated the questions

Comment: What Heroku plan are you on? If you're on one of the lower tiers like Hobby, then you don't get a dedicated app instance and have to share it with other Hobby databases/apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide databases that I am not allowed to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663639/how-to-hide-databases-that-i-am-not-allowed-to-access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get a dedicated PostgreSQL server with Heroku Postgres. Your databases are co-located with other users' databases on the same server. You'll be able to see the names of other users' databases, but you won't be able to access them.

I'm not sure what "crashes my computer" means, but make sure you are selecting *your* database when trying to connect.

Comment: You can hide them via a DB restriction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999660/pgadmin-why-is-db-restriction-and-advanced-properties-disabled