# pgAdmin4: How Can I Get All of my Heroku Postgres Databases to Display in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, pgadmin-4

I have several Heroku Postgres databases that I want to access using pgAdmin4. I'm using version 4.2. I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663639/how-to-hide-databases-that-i-am-not-allowed-to-access) to learn how to hide the databases I don't have access to. I have all the databases entered in **DB restriction**. However when I connect to the Heroku database, only the maintenance account appears in the list of databases. I updated the password file in advanced properties with my .pgpass file. It still only lists the maintenance database.

I've searched here, the Database Administrators Stack Exchange, and the pgAdmin instructions but have not found anything.

Comment: Your databases should all have different connection information (user, password, and even host). Have you configured each database correctly?

Comment: I only have one connection using my main database. The link I used implied that I could list several databases in one connection definition. I came to that conclusion because it stated how to list different Heroku databases in the preferences. There is a way to do that but I cannot figure out how. Adding the connection strings to .pgpass did not work.