# pgadmin db restriction server property not working

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a heroku postgres database. On pgadmin i can see over 1,700 databases since they are all on the same host. I have set the server connection settings as provided by heroku and i can see my database highlighted in yellow and can access it normally.

I tried disconnecting from the server than edit the db restriction property in the advanced tab and put in my database name(same one as the maintenance db, and without ''). I press save, i reconnect to the server but i can still see all the databases of the server and all the live data of the entire server. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don´t download the latest version of pgadmin 4(v.6.10), instead download the v.6.9

link:
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v6.9/windows/

I believe that latest version is buged when we try to especify a dbname for restriction

uninstall 4(v.6.10) and replace (v.6.9)

i faced the same problem here, but installed (v.6.9) and worked great, and brings me only my database

for pgadmin4 you dont need single quotes ... just write the dbname and then tab

[How to hide databases that I am not allowed to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663639/how-to-hide-databases-that-i-am-not-allowed-to-access)

[result-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq1EA.png)

Comment: yep look like it's a bug in v.6.10. Worked after installing v.6.9. Thanks

Comment: The the issue is fixed and will be available in 6.11