# phpPgAdmin for Heroku database

Tags: heroku, phppgadmin, heroku-postgres

When I create an app in Heroku and add a database (PostgreSQL) to it, is there a way to add a web interface for that database (such as phpPgAdmin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I think you can't have this functionality. Have a look at the [monitoring](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#monitoring-logging) section; in case you want to get some logs. Furthermore it's worth checking [Heroku Postgres](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) add-on section. There you can find details about different plans e.g. they include different features.

However, there is a way to connect to Postgres database on Heroku using pgAdmin [not web interface] as answered in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769860/connect-to-a-heroku-database-with-pgadmin) and this [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21869/connecting-pgadmin3-to-postgres-on-heroku).

Hope this helps until some extend.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind running the web interface locally, you can use phppgadmin to manage the Heroku postgreSQL db.

This is easily done by spinning a docker container.

```
docker pull dockage/phppgadmin

docker run --name=phppgadmin-heroku -d --publish=81:80 -e PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST=<your_db_url_from_heroku> -e PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_DEFAULT_DB=<your_db_name_from_heroku> -e PHP_PG_ADMIN_OWNED_ONLY=true dockage/phppgadmin:latest
```

This will run the phppgadmin on http://localhost:81. Of course, the same container could be deployed on Heroku, if a local deployment is not enough for your needs.