# How do I configure phpPgAdmin (hosted on Heroku) to connect to Postgres (hosted on Heroku)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, phppgadmin

I have deployed phpPgAdmin to Heroku, to connect to a Postgres installation.
The admin panel appears and the database shows up under servers properly. With what I am positive are the correct username and password I get "Login failed".

I have read the "I always get “Login failed” even though I'm sure I'm using the right username and password." section of the documentation and the recommendations are config changes to PostgreSQL server - which obviously I cannot change as it is hosted on Heroku.

My config:

```
$conf['servers'][0]['desc'] = 'My Postgres DB';
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com';
$conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 5432;
$conf['servers'][0]['sslmode'] = 'require';
$conf['servers'][0]['defaultdb'] = 'postgres';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dump_path'] = '';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dumpall_path'] = '';
```

Comment: Do you use postgres addon on heroku? Also have a look here, similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17568245/157216

Comment: Yes I use the addon. I am able to use pgAdmin3 as in the link you provided to connect successfully but that is not a hosted application. I'm hoping to use the hosted phpPgAdmin so my team members can just go to a URL and log in to admin the DB.

Comment: Could you please try changing sslmode to 'allow' instead of 'require'? Also, are you sure there is a database named 'postgres'? Finally, try to see if heroku gives you an internal IP address in the form 10.10.x.x to replace the public endpoint CNAME you're using now.

Comment: @amenadiel I used postgres as the db name because of the inline config comment: // For a PostgreSQL 8.1+ server, you can set this to 'postgres'.
Changing to actual db name dbtacm8bssfig5 (it's a test db so ill share the acutal name)

Comment: @amenadiel I don't know which of the changes you suggested fixed the issue but i'm logged in. You rock. Thanks.