# Error connecting to Heroku DB with PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I followed the instructions to [Connect to a heroku database with pgadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769860/connect-to-a-heroku-database-with-pgadmin). What might cause the following error?

```
ERROR: column "*my database identifier*" does not exist. 
LINE 9: WHERE datname IN (*my database identifier*)
```

To be clear *my database identifier* is the alphanumeric string listed in next to "Database" in HerokuPostgres Connection Settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to quote the identifier as a string literal, so PostgreSQL treats it as a column name - for a column that doesn't exist. Try:

```
WHERE datname IN ('my_database_identifier');
```

Note the single quotes.

Comment: Perfect. I put single quotes around my database under Advanced>DB restriction and everything works just fine.