# Trouble connecting to Heroku DB with pgAdmin III client

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I'm running into trouble connecting to a heroku database with pgAdmin3.  I've filled out the Add Server options in pgAdmin3 as described in this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769860/connect-to-a-heroku-database-with-pgadmin).  The error I receive is FATAL: password authentication failed for user "hliegpkjabvrpe".  I can connect to the database with heroku pg:psql.  When I look at the heroku logs -t, I don't see any trace of the failed login.

From the message it looks like pgAdmin3 is reaching the server, but denied.  I've checked and double checked the password.  I'm copying it directly from the heroku page showing the connection parameters.

Is there a place where I can get a more detailed description of why the authentication failed?  Am I missing something obvious here?

I'm running pgAdmin3, version1.18 on windows 8.  I have the heroku db name in the maintainance db slot, as described in the question / answer above.  And I have ssl turned on.  What am I missing?

Any help would be MOST appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same problem and am just as baffled. There is no question I'm using the correct password. I'm copying it directly out of the credentials call, as you are. I can connect through command line with the credentials, as well. Just not PGAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

In case you did't, you need to select "require" for SSL under SSL tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try the credentials given by: `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE`