# Django migrations & Heroku: ProgrammingError at / column does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm having a problem with migrations and heroku.
I have a django 1.7 app that is running locally but I get the following message error from heroku when I run manage.py migrate:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "tag" of relation "website_classificado" does not exist
```

Any ideas? Is there a way to manually add columns to the postgres database through the heroku shell?

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find out why the migrations were not being applied but I found a way to add the columns manually using pgadmin3 connected to my heroku database.
For those curious to know how to do this:
[Connect to a heroku database with pgadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769860/connect-to-a-heroku-database-with-pgadmin)