# Cannot connect via heroku pg:psql (no response) [Windows]

Tags: heroku-postgres

In GitBash:

```
$ heroku pg:psql
--> Connecting to postgresql-rectangular-74530
```

And no response is given... it's just kept there

If I type, for example:

```
$ heroku pg:psql
```

That works great. (I've already set my HEROKU_APP enviroment variable, that's why I'm not passing it as a parameter.)

If I only type psql, like this:

```
$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "MyPCUsername" does not exist
```

An error is thrown... I don't if it has something to do.

I'm on Windows 7 64bits.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I know there are some posts about same thing, but none of them helped me

Answer (score 3):

Run heroku pg:psql in windows command prompt, for some reason not all heroku commands work properly in git bash

Comment: I had this problem just now and running in windows command prompt actually solved it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only "solution" I have is to access with pgAdmin as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769860/connect-to-a-heroku-database-with-pgadmin)

Or install Ubuntu at Virtual Box and accessing via heroku pg:psql. Works like a charm in Linux

Comment: Or you still able to do this? 
I use to connect via pgAdmin but currently not able to?

Comment: Don't know if I got you... I'm able to connect via pgAdmin 4. Take into account that the remote database is always changing. Sory if I don't answer your question